# Can Xbox saved games/profile on a flash drive be backed up to another flash drive?

Tags: xbox-360

I store my profile, saved games and even some arcade games on my USB flash drive (16GB). It makes me really nervous that this flash drive could just die one day, then I lose all my game saves.

So the question is, is there any way to make a backup of this data that could later be restored onto another flash drive?

Comment: I was trying to rsync the data off, then back on to another drive. Just realized the drive I'm trying to transfer to, is 30m smaller, so it fails.

Comment: Cloud storage? You shouldn't be backing up your games anyway. Should only back up your save files.

Comment: Cloud storage is only 500M, iirc. I would only be able to add a handful of saves. Some are quite large (e.g. 200M+).

Comment: Eh? What sort of games do you have? The biggest I've seen is a few megs.

Comment: Skyrim is 135M, FIFA 12 84M, Forza Horizon 24M. Cloud storage is just not enough.

Comment: That is indeed an eye-opener.

Comment: I tried to use the unix utility `dd`, but the xbox did not recognize the copied drive. Seems like there is still some Microsoft voodoo involved.

Comment: I would imagine that there is some way to just flash all the information on the drive to another drive or your pc. The issue is that you would need to get your computer to copy a format that it doesn't understand. (That is the Microsoft voodoo) I am not proficient enough at computers to inform you how. But it just feels like there is some one out there that has figured it out. People have modded game saves and hacked scores, and so on. So I know people have found ways for computers to access and modify these files. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool called [Horizon](http://www.xboxmb.com/horizon/).

With this tool you can backup your save games and even your games in GoD format to your PC. After, you can put these files back to another storage device with this tool.

Comment: I will have to try this when I get a chance, looks like a feasible option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can back up your save games to your HDD on your XBox 360, the Cloud Save Drive which is available for all Xbox Live GOLD membership subscibers (note if your not connected to the interent you cannot access the online drive) and to another USB Drive, however Only game save files can do this, your profile cannot, but can be fully restored and downloaded with a simple login to an xbox console and Full games and most arcade titles cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, Just unhide all files and select it all and copy it onto the other flash drive! I did that before!